# Пунктуация с частицей "ли" и союзом "либо"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

**"Использует ли человек весь потенциал своего мозга - либо спектр его функциональности обычно беден и он [человек] ограничивается небольшим набором умений?"**

Очень смущает тире, да и запятую хочется поставить перед союзом "и".

Comment: Предложение далеко не идеально составлено. Местоимения *его* и *он* не ясно к чему относятся. Потенциал мозга противопоставлен непонятному "спектру функциальности". Есть ли смысл разбираться с пунктуацией или лучше сначала перестроить предложение?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

**Использует ли человек вЕсь потенциал своего мозга — или спектр его функциональности обычно бЕден и ограничивается небольшим набором умЕний?**

Здесь речь идет о спектре функциональности мозга (не человека), набор умений также отнесен к функциями мозга.

Тире — неосновной знак в сложносочиненном предложение, он может применяться при **подчеркнутом противопоставлении.** Обозначает увеличенную паузу в устной речи.

Answer (score 0):

**Использует ли человек весь потенциал своего мозга, или же спектр его функциональности обычно беден и ограничен небольшим набором умений?**

Я бы поставил именно так. При прочтении не возникает удлиненной паузы после "мозга", поэтому тире не слишком уместно. А использовать во второй части "он" в значении "человек" недопустимо по правилу согласования (местоимение заменяет название того объекта, которое последним встречается в тексте и соответствует ему грамматически), к тому же, ограничен набор умений скорее у мозга, чем у человека, и усложнение теряет смысл.

Если **никак нельзя обойтись** без такой формулировки и необходимо тире, то насчет запятой Вы приняли верное решение: обе части присоединяются одним союзом "либо", поэтому не могут быть разделены запятой.